# RichTextBlock text line count

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, richtextblock

I am working on Windows Phone 8.1 application and I got this issue:

I have a `RichTextBlock` control which holds my text, if my control height is bigger than my screen I need to scroll line by line automaticly while the user reads the text.

Is there any way to determine the number of the lines in my `RichTextBlock` or geometric calculation is the only way?

I've tried to iterate over the Blocks collection, but nothing seems to be relevant.

The only thing that I've came with is by using `TextPointer.GetCharacterRect` function:

```
if(msgContainer.Blocks.Any())
{
    var item = msgContainer.Blocks.FirstOrDefault();

    var height = item.LineHeight;
    var startRect = item.ContentStart.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);

    var lineHeight = startRect.Height;
    var lineCount = (int)_fatAssTextMessage.ActualHeight / lineHeight;
}
```

But it isn't accurate - sometimes it misses by line or two since the int casting, and the division...

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `richTextBox.Lines.Count();` ?

Comment: Well, there is not property Lines in my control: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RichTextBlock

Comment: Then count for `'\r'` and `'\n'` in whole text. They are equal to ENTER key or newline.

Comment: @FiN text boxes can wrap, using newline delimiters will not always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get a slightly more accurate count if you do the cast *after* you've done the division:

```
var lineCount = (int)(_fatAssTextMessage.ActualHeight / lineHeight);
```

Currently you are casting the actual height to an integer and *then* doing the division which will always undercount the number of lines.

This will also undercount occasionally - when you have half a line visible. To ensure you always get the largest possible value do something like this:

```
var lineCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(_fatAssTextMessage.ActualHeight / lineHeight);
```

> [`Math.Ceiling`] Returns the smallest integral value that is greater than or equal to the specified double-precision floating-point number.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, it really gets me a better results. I still believe that there suppose to be a better way to deal with this functionality.